# Get id of last created album in Picasa (gdata) PHP

Tags: gdata-api, gdata, picasa

Im trying to insert a photo on a newly created album. But i couldnt find a way on how to get the last generated Album ID.

```
$entry = new Zend_Gdata_Photos_AlbumEntry();
$entry->setTitle($gp->newTitle("Test album"));
$entry->setSummary($gp->newSummary("This is an album."));

$createdEntry = $gp->insertAlbumEntry($entry);
```

From the example on gdata:

```
$username = "default";
$filename = "C:/xampp/htdocs/test.jpg";
$photoName = "My Test Photo";
$albumId = "5626728515640093041";
:
:

// We use the AlbumQuery class to generate the URL for the album
$albumQuery = $gp->newAlbumQuery();

$albumQuery->setUser($username);
$albumQuery->setAlbumId($albumId);

$insertedEntry = $gp->insertPhotoEntry($photoEntry, $albumQuery->getQueryUrl());
```

How can I know the last inserted album without typing it manually?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on http://code.google.com/intl/zh-TW/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#AddAlbums

> Picasa Web Albums creates a new album using the data you sent, then returns an HTTP 201 status code, along with a copy of the new album in the form of an "entry" element. The returned entry is similar to the one you sent, but the returned one contains various elements added by the server, such as an "id" element.

Therefore, you can get the albumID by parse the returned entry.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Use the AlbumQuery class to generate the URL for the album */

$albumQuery = $gp->newAlbumQuery();
$albumQuery->setUser($user);
$albumQuery->setAlbumName($albumName);

/* Insert the photo, and the server returns the entry representing the photo after it is uploaded */

$insertedEntry = $gp->insertPhotoEntry($photoEntry, $albumQuery->getQueryUrl());
$pialbum = $insertedEntry->getGphotoAlbumId()->getText();
$pifoto =  $insertedEntry->getGphotoId()->getText();
```